# Installing geffnet with pip

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I used a google colab notebook to run a certain model. It required me to install geffnet like this.

```
!pip -q install geffnet
```

How can I install geffnet locally?

I tried the line below but I get an error when trying to get efficientnet_b7. 
"RuntimeError: Unknown model (efficientnet_b7)

```
pip3 install geffnet
```

Answer (score 1):

Were your other python installing commands work properly?
Try with a version likethis,

pip install geffnet==0.9.0

Still not working,try to use Pytorch instead of Colab, sometimes issue may be fixed

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't work either. It is quite weird because I can import geffnet. But I have this error later on.